# Função Keyup no input ao carregar um modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

Estou implementando uma função para alterar a senha do usuário logado. 
Quando eu carrego a senha do usuário no componente input ele não valida a senha carregada, a qual está fora da regra estabelecida pela função abaixo. 
Gostaria que, ao carregar o modal, a senha já fosse validada. Atualmente a minha função só valida quando eu apago os dados do componente e volto a dar o foco.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ??

Essa é a minha função em **JS**:

```
$('#inpSenha').keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var letras,
    numeros,
    letrasMaiusculas,
    especial;

  if (/[a-z]/gm.test(value)) {
    letras = " ";
  } else {
    letras = "Letras minúsculas";
  }
  if (/[0-9]/gm.test(value)) {
    numeros = "  ";
  } else {
    numeros = "Números";
  }
  if (/[A-Z]/gm.test(value)) {
    letrasMaiusculas = "  ";
  } else {
    letrasMaiusculas = "letras maiúsculas";
  }
  if (/[!@#$%*()_+^&{}}:;?.]/gm.test(value)) {
    especial = "  ";
  } else {
    especial = "Caracteres especiais não alfaNuméricos";
  }

  $('p').html("A senha deve possuir: " + letras + "|" + numeros + "|" + letrasMaiusculas + "|" + especial)
});
```

Meu componente está assim:

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="modalAlterarUsuario" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div style="color: white; background-color: #0c4677" class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">
           <strong>Preferências</strong>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form novalidate="novalidate" data-toggle="validator" name="frmUsuario" id="formCadastro" role="form">
          <div class="row">

            <div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group" style="height: 200px;">
                  <input class="hide" type='file' id="inputFile" onchange="readURL(this);" />
                  <img title="Clique para alterar a imagem" id="imagemUsuario" class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{usuario.fotoUsuario}}" style="width: 180px;" ng-model="usuario.fotoUsuario" onerror="this.src='./imagem/imgNaoDisponivel.jpg'" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label>Login:</label>
              <input maxlength="20" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.login" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label>Nome:</label>
              <input maxlength="30" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label>E-mail:</label>
              <input maxlength="100" type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label>Senha:</label>
              <input id="inpSenha" required="required" type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.senha" autofocus="autofocus" />
              <span id="numero">A senha deve conter pelo menos um número.</span>
              <br></br>
              <span id="maiuscula">A senha deve conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula.</span>
              <br></br>
              <span id="minuscula">A senha deve conter pelo menos uma letra minúscula.</span>
              <br></br>
              <span id="seis">A senha deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres.</span>
              <br></br>
              <span id="especial">A senha deve conter pelo menos um caractere especial não alfanumérico. </span>
              <br></br>
            </div>    
          </div> 
        </form>
      </div>    
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button style="background-color: #b51e27;  color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default " id="btnSalvar" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="salvarUsuario()">Salvar</button>
        <button style="background-color: #b51e27; color: white;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inclua mais conteúdo do seu html e js, está um tanto confuso para compreender o comportamento atual e o que você deseja

Comment: Eduardo segue jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1013/.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Funcionou perfeitamente!! põe como resposta. Obrigado !

Comment: Fiz outro código, olha na minha resposta como ficou., ele valida a senha ao carregar modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este evento é disparado quando o modal foi tornado visível para o usuário:

```
$('#modalAlterarUsuario').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // seu código js
});
```

Segue exemplo em jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1014/

Ou pode fazer isso:

```
$(document).on('#modalAlterarUsuario','shown.bs.modal', function (e) { 
   // seu código js 
});
```

Comment: pode acrescentar o document em seu codigo $(document).on('#modalAlterarUsuario','shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // seu código js
});

Answer (score 0):

Olá @eduardo-krakhecke!

Creio que você pode conseguir melhor resultado separando a função de validação e chamando-a tanto no evento keyup quanto no evento show da modal. Se você estiver usando um framework (como Bootstrap) para criar sua modal, você pode chamar a função de validação no evento apropriado (show) e adaptá-la para ser atribuída ao valor do seu campo de senha (eu não encontrei no HTML que você citou algo parecido com um campo de senha...). 
Enfim, creio que sua função de validação pode receber o elemento como parâmetro ao invés de ficar isolada num elemento específico, assim fica modular.

Veja se isto pode ser útil: https://jsfiddle.net/GustavoAdolfo/xakhc5av/

O que acha de fazer esse teste e nos falar o resultado?
Sucesso!